# Are certain keydown-event combinations blocking each other?

Tags: javascript, events, key

I have a beginner's question on JavaScript: In a small testing script I oberserved that some key-events seemingly do not trigger when others are already triggered. In other words: If some keys are down, most of the other keydown-events are kind of blocked. For example holding down keys a, s, d, f, g do not trigger the keydown-event for g. However, If I am holding e.g. h and j down, too, their keydown-event is triggered as expected.

For this test I've used Mozilla Firefox 26.0 on Windows 7 Home Edition 64-Bit.

Here is the included JavaScript file which is used to output the map of key-events with keydown-type to some div-element with id `"testout001"`:

```
var keyMap = [];

function keyMapToHTML(arr){
    var i = 0;
    var temp = "";
    while(i<arr.length){
        if(arr[i]){
            temp += i + "<br>";
        }
        i++;
    }
    return temp;
}

function keyHandler(e){
    e = e || event; // deal with IE
    keyMap[e.keyCode] = (e.type == 'keydown');
    document.getElementById("testout001").innerHTML = keyMapToHTML(keyMap);
}
```

---

1. **First of all: Is this a bug?**
2. **Why are certain keydown-combinations working while others won't?**
3. **Are there limits (most likely browser-specific) to how many keys can be hold down/pressed at the same time?**

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common hardware issue with most keyboards. Certain keypresses just cannot be detected at the same time.

Comment: Good, that you pointed that out. Over the years I totally forgot about this technical restriction. After reading your answer I searched for it on the web and found for example the following explanation on key blocking: http://uberoptions.net/logitech-keyblocking.